# How do you get rid of large quantities of water in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Someone made a massive lake on my world and I want to get rid of it, preferably by filling it in. But I would like to do it quickly, is there a fast way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If turning the top layer into cobblestones works for you, just dump a lava bucket near the lake (NOT INTO THE WATER, just close to it) and let it flow into the water.  Scoop it up, move it closer, and repeat.  As the lava flow hits water they'll turn into cobblestones.

If you accidentally dump the lava into the water you'll get obsidian instead and lose your lava.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your hands on it a good amount of [Sponge](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Sponge)s would be helpful.
Otherwise (if you don't care what's below the cobble) use Lava like mentioned or Sand/Gravel to dump them into the water, if you want all the water gone.

A possible alternative would be to use [Sugar Cane](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Sugarcane)s, if you just want to get rid of water without dumping 1000s of blocks into the lake. They're easy to come by and easy to get rid of.

Other solutions:

- WorldEdit and `//drain` (yes, there is one for PE)
- Fill lake with burnable material (wood, leaves) and burn it once filled.

Comment: WorldEdit for PE link please!?

Comment: http://mcpedl.com/worldedit-pe/ this is one for example